# Using MailParse when piping email

Tags: php, email, pipe, email-parsing

I'm having an issue with MailParse.

I have MailParse installed but I can't get it to run when I send an email to the address I'm using to pipe to my script. I also get a bounced email every time I try to run it.

I've tried using the following hashbangs at the top of my php script.

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
#!/usr/bin/php -c /path/to/php.ini
#!/usr/bin/php -c/path/to/php.ini
#!/usr/bin/php -qc/path/to/php.ini
```

To test if MailParse is loading I'll do something like this.

```
if(function_exists(mailparse_msg_create)) //do something
else (function_exists(mailparse_msg_create)) //do something else
```

MailParse seems to work when I execute my script in my browser but not when I send an email to it.

Also, when I include either of the last 2 hashbangs I get this in the email bounce back.

```
Failed loading /usr/php/56/usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendGuardLoader.so:  /usr/php/56/usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendGuardLoader.so: undefined symbol: zend_new_interned_string
Failed loading /usr/php/56/usr/lib64/php/modules/opcache.so:  /usr/php/56/usr/lib64/php/modules/opcache.so: undefined symbol: zend_new_interned_string
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/php/56/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so' - /usr/php/56/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so: undefined symbol: zend_new_interned_string in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/php/56/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/php/56/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_sqlite: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20131226, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_pgsql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20131226, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
```

When I use code in my script that doesn't call for a MailParse function when I send an email there are no problems. It just seems to be that MailParse won't load when I send emails.

Comment: Is MailParse even supposed to work by piping to it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I wasn't referencing the correct php cli binary in my hashbang. I'm using BlueHost and PHP 5.6 so it should have been

```
#!/usr/php/56/bin/php-cgi
```